# guessing game - how to make it better?

Tags: python-3.x, function

since my last question I got a little better. No more syntax issues question I hope. Anyway.

I was doing this exercise to create guessing game that would generate number and ask user for input. I was able to make it work but I do not like my code.

The thing is, in functions I created I am using variables from outside of that function. Which as I understand is not good in terms of writing good code. Can anyone advise on how can I make that better ? Should I ditch the function all together ? I would like to keep it in some form. Thanks in advance !

```
import random

counter = 0

def result_check(num):
    if guess == rng_number:
        print("Bravo")
    else:
        print("Wrong!, The number is {0}".format(rng_number))

while True:
    reply = input("Do you want to play ? Y/N: ")
    rng_number  = random.randint(0,9)
    counter += 1
    if reply == "Y":
        guess = int(input("Select a digit between 0 and 9: "))
        result_check(guess)
    elif reply == "N":
        print("You played {0} times".format(counter))
        break
```

Comment: If your code works and is complete, but could be improved, it should be on Code Review instead. This site is primarily for fixing broken code.

Comment: @Carcigenicate As `rng_number` is defined in the main body of the script (along with `guess`), it is a `global` variable, so can therefore be accessed from anywhere else (including inside `functions`) - have a look [at this](http://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html) which explains it better than I can!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine as it is, however there a couple of things that I would change. First of all, if you would like to use a n explicit checking `function`, then you should `pass` both the `guess` and the `rng_number`as two separate `parameters`. The way it is at the moment, you `pass` the `guess` in to the `parameter` `num`, but `num` is not used to the checking `function`. The function is looking in the scope it is being called from and getting the guess and random number from there. So that is the first thing I would change - explicitly passing the `variables` into the `function`.

Although saying all this, to me it seems silly to use a `function` at all! As all you have in there is an `if...else` statement, it just seems simpler to just move that into the main code. By doing this, you save the need of passing `parameters` into a `function` *and* you tidy up the code by removing a few lines which is always good! **:)**

Here is the code with the code from the `function` moved into the main section. I also removed the unnecessary `0` in the `string` `formatting`...

```
import random

counter = 0

while True:
    reply = input("Do you want to play ? Y/N: ")
    rng_number  = random.randint(0,9)
    counter += 1
    if reply == "Y":
        guess = int(input("Select a digit between 0 and 9: "))
        if guess == rng_number:
            print("Bravo")
        else:
            print("Wrong!, The number is {}".format(rng_number))
    elif reply == "N":
        print("You played {} times".format(counter))
        break
```

Comment: This makes sense, it does indeed look like function was unnecessary here. This community is amazing, thank you for insight :)

Comment: @crookedteeth please up-vote and accept then to show your appreciation!

Comment: I did not know about 'accepting'. Consider it done :)